# <a> onClick event but still proceed to href target

Tags: javascript, html, jsonp

I have a link as follows:

```
<a onclick="runSomeJsonpCall();" href="www.goherenext.com"> make this work </a>
```

The javascript method does your basic JSONP call, something like this:

```
function runSomeJsonpCall() {
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "http://jsonpurl.com?parameter1=" + "someparam";
document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

My JSONP call never actually executes, unless I put in return false to the onlick event, but then of course the href doesn't navigate to the target.

How do I get both things to work?

NOTE: I can use pure JavaScript only, no libraries

Comment: You can try setting window.location with JavaScript, as part of your onclick event.

Comment: As far as I know, `<a>`'s `onclick` and `href` properties are mutually exclusive. Just make the redirection part of your json call.

Comment: What tom said would probably work. Curious, why would you want to inject a script tag and also navigate away (and on the same tab)? The script wouldn't even get to load...

Comment: it's a tracking module, the injected jsonp call tracks the link was clicked.

Comment: I've heard of scratch and sniff, but never the on "lick" event.

Comment: @redolent Reactive UI, its all the rage now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should prevent default event ...
  look there : [event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault) something like that ...

```
function runSomeJsonpCall(event) {

    if (!event) var event = window.event;
    if (event.preventDefault) {
       event.preventDefault();
    }else{
       // IE
       event.returnValue = false;
    }
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "http://jsonpurl.com?parameter1=" + "someparam";
    document.body.appendChild(script);

   // you should wait for jsonp loading
   // here i use an ID to retreive  the element but you can do your way ...
   setTimeout("changeLocation('"+ document.getElementById('linkID').href +"')", 1000);
}
changeLocation(location) {
    window.location.href = location;
}
```

Personnaly, i really don't like the use of inline onclick attribute, i'll use addEventListener or attachEvent ... i think it's a beeter way :)

Comment: Used a simplified version of this code (didn't use preventdefault, just "return false"). The setTimeout() is required, although I shortened it to 50ms.

Answer (score 0):

```
function runSomeJsonpCall(obj) {
    //...
    document.location=obj.getAttribute('href');
    return false;
}

<a onclick="runSomeJsonpCall(self);" href="http://www.goherenext.com"> make this work </a>
```

Also Note http:// in href link

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
<a onclick="runSomeJsonpCall();" href="#"> make this work </a>
```

and:

```
function runSomeJsonpCall() {
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "http://jsonpurl.com?parameter1=" + "someparam";
document.body.appendChild(script);
window.location("www.goherenext.com");
}
```